# Image in product.tpl only in some categories

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I created in my prestashop site a rule in the product.tpl file to show an image only in specific categories. Given the number of categories involved (those where the image is shown), I opted to show the image in all categories, except in some. I have insert this code in my product page:

```php
{if $ category-> id! = 78 AND $ category-> id! = 64 AND $ category-> id! = 29 AND $ category-> id! = 91 AND $ category-> id! = 92 AND $ category- > id! = 93 AND $ category-> id! = 94 AND $ category-> id! = 95 AND $ category-> id! = 102 AND $ category-> id! = 17 AND $ category-> id! = 71 AND $ category-> id! = 106 AND $ category-> id! = 107 AND $ category-> id! = 109 AND $ category-> id! = 72 AND $ category-> id! = 101 AND $ category-> id! = 96 AND $ category-> id! = 97 AND $ category-> id! = 75 AND $ category-> id! = 69 AND $ category-> id! = 100 AND $ category-> id! = 73 AND $ category-> id! = 70 AND $ category-> id! = 65 AND $ category-> id! = 80 AND $ category-> id! = 81 AND $ category-> id! = 82 AND $ category-> id ! = 84 AND $ category-> id! = 83 AND $ category-> id! = 79 AND $ category-> id! = 110 AND $ category-> id! = 79 AND $ category-> id! = 111 AND $ category-> id! = 79 AND $ category-> id! = 112 AND $ category-> id! = 79 AND $ category-> id! = 113 AND $ category-> id! = 79 AND $ category-> id! = 66 AND $ category-> id! = 79 AND $ category-> id! = 85 AND $ category-> id! = 79 AND $ category-> id! = 86 AND $ category-> id! = 79 AND $ category-> id! = 87 AND $ category-> id! = 79 AND $ category-> id! = 90 AND $ category-> id! = 79 AND $ category-> id! = 67 AND $ category-> id! = 79 AND $ category-> id! = 68 AND $ category-> id! = 79 AND $ category-> id! = 74 AND $ category-> id! = 79 AND $ category-> id! = 104 AND $ category-> id! = 79 AND $ category-> id ! = 108 AND $ category-> id! = 79 AND $ category-> id! = 15 AND $ category-> id! = 79 AND $ category-> id! = 340 AND $ category-> id! = 1457 AND $ category-> id! = 1497 AND $ category-> id! = 1498 AND $ category-> id! = 1499 AND $ category-> id! = 1417 AND $ category-> id! = 1501 AND $ category-> id! = 1524}
          <Div> IMAGE </ div>
```

This mode works but it consumes too many resources on the server, how can I do the same thing in a cleaner way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add all excluded categories in a variable and then test it :

```
{assign var='excluded_categories_ids' value=[78, 64, 29, 91, 92, 93 ...]}
{if (!in_array($category->id, $excluded_categories_ids))}
    <div>Image</div>
{endif}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
With this method can I insert so many ids of categories without weighing down the system?

Answer (score 2):

Said that it does not consume so many resources, a cleaner way to do that is:

```
{php}
$excluded_categories_ids = [78, 64, ...];
{/php}

{if (!in_array($category->id, $excluded_categories_ids))}
    <div></div>
{endif}
```

Even if I read that the `{php}` use is deprecated

**UPDATED**

Since `{php}` tag is deprecated you can use this:

```
{assign var='excluded_categories_ids' value=[78, 64, ...]}
```

Comment: To omit the usage of deprecated {php} you can define it with the combination {assign var='excluded_categories_ids' value=[78, 64]}